# Linking different Protobuf files C#

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, csproj, grpc-c#, grpc-dotnet

I'm trying to link protobuf together from different projects in my solution.
I seem to get File Not Found errors every time I build and can't find a way for the protobuf compiler to find the files.

The following protobuf files i'm using also a note that I trimmed some small things.

Project A

Service/Identity/Protos/User.Proto

```
import "Identity/Protos/Common.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "Service.Identity";

package user;

service ProfileController {
    rpc CreateProfile(CreateProfileRequest) returns (common.GenericResult);
}
```

Project B

Shared/Protos/Common.Proto

```
option csharp_namespace = "Shared";

package common;

message GenericResult {
    bool success = 1;
    string exceptions = 2;
}
```

In the csproj files the following settings have been made.

Project A

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Identity\Protos\User.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    <Protobuf Include="..\Shared\Protos\Common.proto" Link="Identity\Protos\Common.proto" ProtoRoot=".." GrpcServices="None" >
    </Protobuf>
```

Project B

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\Common.proto" GrpcServices="None" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The link seems to work but I can't import it in my user.proto
[image: Common Link]

When I try and import it which I have tried in the following import statements in my user.proto seems to be able to find it.

```
import "Identity/Protos/Common.proto";
import "Protos/Common.proto";
import "Common.proto";
import "/Identity/Protos/Common.proto";
```

It gives me the following error.
[image]

All i want to do is be able to use the Common.Proto in my User.Proto. But it just does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to set your User.proto as a Link too.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Protobuf Include="..\Identity\Protos\User.proto" Link="Identity\Protos\User.proto" ProtoRoot=".." GrpcServices="Server" />
   <Protobuf Include="..\Shared\Protos\Common.proto" Link="Identity\Protos\Common.proto" ProtoRoot=".." GrpcServices="None" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And also I will rather use Common.proto's original folder structure not changing it to `Identity\Protos\Common.proto`. It could be confusing in the future.

I have configured it like this:

```
<!-- External project protobufs -->
<Protobuf Include="..\MultipleProtobufFiles.Contracts\Configuration\user_configuration.proto" GrpcServices="None" ProtoRoot="..">
    <Link>MultipleProtobufFiles.Contracts\Configuration\user_configuration.proto</Link>
</Protobuf>
    

<!-- This project service protobuf -->
<Protobuf Include="..\MultipleProtobufFiles\server_communication.proto" GrpcServices="Both" ProtoRoot="..">
    <Link>server_communication.proto</Link>
</Protobuf>
```

Maybe it will help, I fought with it few days ago and won in the end.